# knapsack with google or-tools (c#)

Tags: c#, optimization, knapsack-problem, bin-packing, or-tools

I'm trying to implement knapsack problem with 3 constraint with google-or tools.
Let's say i want to have an additional property called size for each of the item. So each item with have 3 property and i have to maximize the total value for the items.

```
KnapsackSolver k = new KnapsackSolver(KnapsackSolver.KNAPSACK_DYNAMIC_PROGRAMMING_SOLVER, "mybin");
        long[, ,] profits = { {{ 10,20,30} ,{40,50,60}} };
        long[,] weights = {{44,21}};
        long[] capa = { 110 };
        k.Init(profits, weights, capa);
```

But it is not going anywhere. can somebody please correct me.

Comment: Did you try `k.Solve()`? What happens?

Comment: no i did not. cause `k.Init(profits, weights, capa);` this line of code showing wrong.

Comment: "this line of code showing wrong." -> What does that mean? Did you get a compilation error? What was the error? You have to give more details if you want to get help.

Comment: it says invalid parameter list

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/dotnet/csknapsack.cs

```
long[] profits = { 360, 83, 59, 130, 431, 67, 230, 52, 93,
                   125, 670, 892, 600, 38, 48, 147, 78, 256,
                   63, 17, 120, 164, 432, 35, 92, 110, 22,
                   42, 50, 323, 514, 28, 87, 73, 78, 15,
                   26, 78, 210, 36, 85, 189, 274, 43, 33,
                   10, 19, 389, 276, 312 };

long[,] weights = { { 7, 0, 30, 22, 80, 94, 11, 81, 70,
                      64, 59, 18, 0, 36, 3, 8, 15, 42,
                      9, 0, 42, 47, 52, 32, 26, 48, 55,
                      6, 29, 84, 2, 4, 18, 56, 7, 29,
                      93, 44, 71, 3, 86, 66, 31, 65, 0,
                      79, 20, 65, 52, 13 } };

long[] capacities = { 850 };
```

profits is a `long[]`
weights is `long[,]`
capacities is a `long[]`.